# Unable to download data from the API using UNIX wget?

Tags: support, api, gzip

I want to download the JSON data from [this sample API call](http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search/advanced?pagesize=5&fromdate=1420761600&todate=1420934400&order=desc&sort=activity&accepted=True&answers=1&tagged=hadoop&site=stackoverflow&filter=withbody) into a file.

I tried using wget, like so:

```
wget -O ~/ks/json.txt "http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search/advanced?pagesize=5&fromdate=1420761600&todate=1420934400&order=desc&sort=activity&accepted=True&answers=1&tagged=hadoop&site=stackoverflow&filter=withbody"
```

The output I get is not in readable format. The same command works for other web services. Is the Stack Exchange API restricting something or am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**The API documentation states that the API always returns a compressed response**](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/compression):

> ...we guarantee that all responses are compressed, either with GZIP or DEFLATE.

GZIP is the default.

This means that you must send the results from `wget` to `gunzip`.  Like so:

```
wget -O- <URL> | gunzip > results.json
```

Or, in your specific example:

```
wget -O- "http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search/advanced?pagesize=1&fromdate=1420761600&todate=1420934400&sort=activity&accepted=True&answers=1&tagged=hadoop&site=stackoverflow&filter=withbody" | gunzip > ~/ks/json.txt
```